# Why I can't read my line using Java Scanner

Tags: java

How can I read string containing spaces using `Scanner` class, for example `"Bolt Penguin"`? Do I need to remove the whitespaces?
But I can't, I must keep the spaces between the two characters. Here is the program I created:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Shop {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner You = new Scanner(System.in);
   //Your Money
        int money;
        String name;
   //Your Cards
        String Cards;
   //Shop (M) Cards
        int Bolt_Penguin = 100;
        int Eldeen = 95;
        int Jinn = 1020;
   //Shop (S) Cards
        int Dark_Energy = 500;
        int Horn_Unicorn = 640;
        int Sparks = 90;
   //Shop (T) Cards
        int Hidden_S = 800;

     ... //You don't have to see the whole program

       name = You.next();
       if(name.equals("Bolt Penguin")){ //Here it is Bolt (space) Penguin
           System.out.println("Seller: That'll cost " + Bolt_Penguin);
       }else if(name.equals("Eldeen")){
           System.out.println("Seller: That'll cost " + Eldeen);  
       }else if(name.equals("Jinn the Mystical Genie of the Lamp")){
           System.out.println("Seller: That'll cost " + Jinn);
       }else{
           System.out.println("Seller: We don't have that Card yet! ");
       }

      ...
```

Do I need to do something different?

Comment: Please post the error trace.

Comment: "You don't have to see the whole program" - no, but we *would* like to see a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, along with  a good description of what that problem is.

Comment: Define "doesn't work."  What indication do you have that there's a problem?

Comment: If it doesn't work, you need to fix it.

Comment: Can you at least post what's the error you are getting.

Comment: When you have a bug in your program, I suggest you use your debugger to determine what your program is doing and why.  If you don't understand what `next()` does for example, you can read the Javadoc to see how it differs from `nextLine()` hint, hint ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
name = You.nextLine();
```

to read whole line with spaces.

You may also want to change `equals` with `equalsIgnoreCase`, but it depends on your requirements:

```
name = You.nextLine();
if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("Bolt Penguin")) {
    System.out.println("Seller: That'll cost " + Bolt_Penguin);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

replace

`name = You.next();`

by

`name = You.nextLine();`

I tested it with input `Bolt Penguin`

My output is = `Seller: That'll cost 100`

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
name = You.next();
```

with

```
name = You.nextLine();
```